# Rate of convergence of $\frac{a^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality

It is a well-known result from calculus that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^n}{n!} =0,$$
for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$. However, the classical proof involves proving the convergence of the infinite series
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n!}.$$
I am working on some numerical algorithms at the moment. I am wondering if, for every $\epsilon>0$, we can construct an $\mathbf{\text{explicit formula}}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (in terms of $a$ and $\epsilon$) such that
$$ \bigg| \frac{a^n}{n!} \bigg| < \epsilon.$$
Do I need to use any special inequality for this? Any ideas?

Comment: At a quick glance, the arithmetic mean - geometric mean inequality looks like it could be useful here.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi This inequality gives $ \frac{a^n}{n!} \leq \big[ a \big( \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{1} \big) \frac{1}{n} \big]^n$.

Comment: @Zestylemonzi  But then we would need a tighter bound for $\frac{1}{n} + \ldots \frac{1}{1}$ other than $n$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n} + \ldots \frac{1}{1} < \frac{1}{n} +n-1= \frac{n^2-n+1}{n}$ this is one

Comment: i got this inequality from stirling approximation and other aggressive inequalities: $n > e\left| \frac{a}{\epsilon}\right|$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Stirling's Approximation for $n!$,
$$\frac{|a|^n}{n!}<\frac{|a|^n}{\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+1/2}e^{-n}}<\frac{|a|^n}{\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n}e^{-n}}$$ so it is sufficient to solve

$$\begin{align}
\frac{|a|^n}{\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n}e^{-n}}
&<\varepsilon\\
\frac{|a|^ne^{n}}{n^{n}}
&<\sqrt{2\pi}\varepsilon\\
\left(\frac{|a|e}{n}\right)^n
&<\sqrt{2\pi}\varepsilon\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\varepsilon}
&<\left(\frac{n}{|a|e}\right)^n\\
\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\varepsilon}\right)^{\frac{1}{|a|e}}
&<\left(\frac{n}{|a|e}\right)^{\frac{n}{|a|e}}\\
-\frac{1}{|a|e}\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\varepsilon\right)
&<\frac{n}{|a|e}\ln\left(\frac{n}{|a|e}\right)\\
W\left(-\frac{1}{|a|e}\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\varepsilon\right)\right)
&<W\left(\frac{n}{|a|e}\ln\left(\frac{n}{|a|e}\right)\right)\\
W\left(-\frac{1}{|a|e}\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\varepsilon\right)\right)
&<\ln\left(\frac{n}{|a|e}\right)
\end{align}$$

where $W$ is the Lambert function. So it suffices to take $$n=\left\lceil |a|e\cdot e^{W\left(-\frac{1}{|a|e}\ln\left(\sqrt{2\pi}\varepsilon\right)\right)}\right\rceil$$

For example, with $a=100$, $\varepsilon=0.01$, this gives $n=276$. Direct computation (with a computer) of $\frac{100^{276}}{276!}\approx0.00035$ shows this is only a tad smaller than $0.01$. Trial and error with a computer's help reveals that the critical $n$ is $273$. This is evidence that the bound is pretty close to sharp.

(Computing values of $W$ is beyond most simple computing devices. But a Computer Algebra System can handle it. At WolframAlpha for example, you can use `LambertW(...)`.)

Comment: While the bound is crude in the answer that I posted, it suffices for purposes herein.  And the development is rather painless and leads to a fairly simple expression.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV Agreed..

Comment: Alex, I do see the virtue of obtaining a tighter bound.  But, I have not been able to find a "tight" bound here.

Comment: @Dr.MV Edited with a different approach that is closer to sharp.

Comment: Well done!   a +1.

Answer (score 3):

Fix $a$.  Then, take $n>2a^2$.  Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{a^n}{n!}&\le \frac{a^n}{(n/2)^{n/2}}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{n/2}}\right)^n\\\\
&\le \frac{a}{\sqrt{n/2}}\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $n>2a^2\max\left(1,\frac{1}{\epsilon^2}\right)$.

Comment: May you please explain why $n! \geq (n/2)^{n/2}$?

Comment: Sure Richard.  Note that for $n=2m$ (i.e. $n$ is even), we have $(2m)!=(2m)(2m-1)(2m-2)\cdots (m+1)m(m-1)\cdots 1$.  Clearly this exceeds $m^m$ since the first $m$ terms are in fact greater than $m$.  Thus we have $n!>(n/2)^{n/2}$ for even $n$.  The case for $n$ odd follows similarly.  -Mark